# Investigation of Body Motion in SolidWorks: Euler Angles Rate or Angular Velocity?

Tags: dynamics, aerospace-engineering, solid-mechanics, solidworks, kinematics

This is my first question in this community.

I decided to demonstrate my problem on simple rigid body, but task may be applied to more complex shapes. So, a cube is built in SolidWorks:

[image]

---

Using the *Motion Analysis* module, I specify 3 *Motors* to rotate the face around the corresponding axis and three angular speed components:

[image]

These speeds are set as follows (in general, they can be set arbitrarily): $v=[45\sin(t);45\sin(2t);45\sin(3t)]$

---

As a result, we get the combined movement of the body, formed by each individual motor on the corresponding face of a cube.

**My question is this:** Is the vector that I formed the *Euler Angles Rate* $\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\alpha}\\\dot{\beta}\\\dot{\gamma}\end{bmatrix}$ or the *Angular Velocity* vector $\omega=\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_x\\\omega_y\\\omega_z\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: That depends on whether the motors move with the rotating body (eg satellite firing thrusters) or are fixed to ground.

Comment: @GregLocock the motors move along with the cube, because  fixed on the edge, not on the ground

Comment: @GregLocock Do I understand correctly that these rotations occur in the body's coordinate system? And do I need to transform them into an inertial frame of reference to get the components of the angular velocity vector?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer involves more than I care to type. It is in any solid mechanics textbook. But roughly speaking, applying torques in an accelerating reference frame, such as a rotating body, involves cross products.

Comment: @GregLocock Yesterday's experiments in the SW showed that in order to calculate the kinetic energy of a body, it is necessary to use the angular velocities in the inertial coordinate system. To do this, I had to simulate the movement of a gyroscope. So far, I do not know how to recalculate vectors from the inertial frame of reference to the body coordinate system. I know that for this we need to use a skew-symmetric matrix of angular velocities, but there, as far as I understand, everything depends on the sequence of rotations around the axes. This sequence for SW is unknown to me.

Comment: Yes, you need a textbook.

Comment: @GregLocock There are so many ... Recommend one, please, and I'll try to figure it out

Comment: @dtn the comment "*the motors move along with the cube*" is not as simple as it sounds. A motor has a stator and a rotor. The attachment to the cube freezes only five out of the six degrees of freedom of the stator assuming that the rotor is attached to the cube. What **exactly** is being applied to the cube in the software? Is it torque (whose axis is fixed as normal to the cube face) or is it angular velocity? If it is angular velocity, then you need to be sure what reference frame the software is using as the ref for the angular velocity. It might not match your intuition or requirement.

Comment: @AJN An angular velocity was applied to the axis fixed along the normal of the cube face. The normals to the face of the cube form a new basis, which changes its position along with the change in the position of the cube.

Comment: Sounds like $\omega$ to me.